# MySQL select the create date's display number

Tags: php, mysql

I have a columns that has the time stamp when a row is created.

I need to find a way to get all the rows from the same 'day', and give each row a display number to show something like this:

```
+---------------------+
| order_date          | // output should be:
+---------------------+
| 2016-05-11 13:01:41 | // 2016051101
| 2016-05-11 15:54:14 | // 2016051102
| 2016-05-11 17:16:18 | // 2016051103
| 2016-05-11 17:35:12 | // 2016051104
| 2016-05-11 17:55:16 | // 2016051105
| 2016-05-12 07:16:48 | // 2016051201
| 2016-05-12 09:30:57 | // 2016051202
| 2016-05-12 09:56:19 | // 2016051203
| 2016-05-13 11:27:21 | // 2016051301
| 2016-05-14 10:15:56 | // 2016051401
| 2016-05-15 11:35:07 | // 2016051501
| 2016-05-15 11:39:48 | // 2016051502
| 2016-05-15 11:40:12 | // 2016051503
+---------------------+
```

Can Mysql do this? or should the program, like php, handle this?

---

Final query I use:

```
    SELECT t.order_date, 
    concat(
    DATE_FORMAT(t.order_date, '%Y%m%d'), 
    LPAD(
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM hz_order s WHERE s.order_date<= t.order_date AND DATE(s.order_date) = DATE(t.order_date)),
2,
0))display 
    FROM hz_order t 
    ORDER BY `display` ASC
```

Comment: I'm a tad unsure if you want the select query to also generate and insert a order number, or if the order number all ready exist.

Comment: No insert needed, the order has it's id, but the order number with day-count is for display only.

Comment: What is the `order number` for? I assume this is actually just the `order in which they were created` and nothing to do with `product orders`

Comment: @RiggsFolly  I've changed the term, it a display number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with a correlated query, like this:

```
SELECT t.order_date,
       concat(DATE_FORMAT(t.order_date, '%Y%m%d'),
              (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourTable s
               WHERE s.order_date<= t.order_date
                 AND DATE(s.order_date) = DATE(t.order_date)))
FROM YourTable t
```

This will generate the date as yyyymmdd+the count.

Comment: the right syntax to use near 'FROM hz_order t' at line 6

Comment: @NobleDinasaur Just add in the `concat` after the first comma : `'0',` .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do this by -

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(date_field, '%Y%m%d'), 
LPAD(COUNT(date_field), 2, '0')) 
FROM table_name
GROUP BY DATE(date_field)
ORDER BY date_field DESC
```

`DATE_FORMAT(date_field, '%Y%m%d')` would format the date like `yyyymmdd`.

`LPAD(COUNT(date_field), 2, '0')` would generate a string with left padding (with 0) to 2 places with the count of that date.

Comment: I got an error : #1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'projecthz.hz_order.order_date' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Even without FULL_GROUP_BY, this isn't quite right. This will simply concatenate the string with a count of all values for that day.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using MySQL. Other methods will be faster on larger data sets.

```
SELECT x.*
     , CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(x.order_date,'%Y%m%d'),LPAD(COUNT(*),2,0))oi 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON DATE(y.order_date) = DATE(x.order_date) 
   AND y.order_date <= x.order_date 
 GROUP  
    BY x.order_date;
```